# json.net IEnumerable

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, json.net

I have the following json file

```
{"fields":[
  {
     "status":"active",
     "external_id":"title",
     "config":{},
     "field_id":11848871,
     "label":"Title",
     "values":[
        {
           "value":"Test Deliverable"
        }
     ],
     "type":"text"
  },{
     "status":"active",
     "external_id":"client-name",
     "config":{},
     "field_id":12144855,
     "label":"Client Name",
     "values":[
        {
           "value":"Chcuk Norris"
        }
     ],
     "type":"text"
  }}
```

And I want to select the value of the field that has its external_id = "title" for example, I'm using Json.Net and already parsed the object. How do i do this using lambda or linq on the Json object, I trird something like this

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
Title = o["fields"].Select(q => q["extenral_id"].Values[0] == "title");
```

Which is not event correct in terms of syntax. I'm not very proficient in Lambda or Linq thought its been there for a while. Appreciate the help

Thanks

Yehia

Comment: by the way, your json there is missing a closing array tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can do this:

```
 string json = "{\"fields\":[{\"status\":\"active\",\"external_id\":\"title\",\"config\":{},\"field_id\":11848871,\"label\":\"Title\",\"values\":[{\"value\":\"Test Deliverable\"}],\"type\":\"text\"},{\"status\":\"active\",\"external_id\":\"client-name\",\"config\":{},\"field_id\":12144855,\"label\":\"Client Name\",\"values\":[{\"value\":\"Chcuk Norris\"}],\"type\":\"text\"}]}";

 JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

 JArray arr = (JArray)obj["fields"];

 var externalIds = arr.Children().Select(m=>m["external_id"].Value<string>());
```

externalIds is a IEnumerable array of string

Or you can chain it together and select the object in one line:

```
var myVal = JObject.Parse(json)["fields"].Children()
                                        .Where(w => w["external_id"].ToString() == "title")
                                        .First();
```

From there you can append whatever selector you want ie if you want the external_id value then append   ["external_id"].ToString()   to the end of the first() selector.

Comment: but here I'm returning the list of external Id, what if I want the Value of the field that has its external_id a specific value

Comment: I don't think parsing the JSON twice like you do in your first example is a good idea. It's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Build classes for your objects first, then parse them so you can access them correctly and its no anonymous type anymore.

For example this classes:

```
class MyJson {
    public List<MyField> fields {get;set;}
}

class MyField {
    public string status {get;set;}
    public string external_id {get;set;}
    // and so on
}
```

Then use that class for parsing the json (don't know the exact syntax right now) like this:

```
var o = Json.Parse(json, typeof(MyJson));
```

And then you can select your data easily with Linq and have intellisense in VS (or similar dev env):

```
var myData = o.fields.Where(q=>q.external_id=="title");
```

Comment: would I need to include every key in the json in the MyField class even if I won't use it, because the json is very long an deep

Comment: No, you only have to put in the properties you need. And in the parsing process only these are filled (of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you had your JSON converted to objects (basically what Marc suggested), the LINQ query would look something like:

```
o.fields.Single(q => q.external_id == "title")
```

But if you don't want to do that, you have to access the values by string keys. If you don't want to convert the type of the value, you can simply use indexing (`["key"]`). But if you want to convert the type, you can use `Value<Type>("key")`. Putting it together, the whole query might be:

```
o["fields"].Single(q => q.Value<string>("external_id") == "title")
```